# Unable to ping within VLAN

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vlan

I have following systems connected in the same network.

**System A**

```
eth0 > 10.25.1.221 netmask=255.255.240.0
```

**System B**

```
eth0 > 10.25.1.142 netmask=255.255.240.0
```

---

Now, i had setup VLAN interfaces on both "System A" and "System B" as following.

**System A**

```
vconfig add eth0 22
ifconfig eth0.22 192.168.3.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

**System B**

```
vconfig add eth0 22
ifconfig eth0.22 192.168.3.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

---

However, I'm not able to ping "Sytem A" <-> "System B". 
Am i missing something here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any other hosts inside the VLAN (like router or something else) which you can ping to see if that will work?

Comment: How are systems A and B connected to each other?